# Print next characters in line Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, search, text

I am looking to make a simple program that will find a character and then print the next 10 characters in the line.  I have only been able to make it print out the whole line and the rest of line is useless. This is what i have for now.

```
f = open("Active Notship.txt", "r")
searchlines = f.readlines()
f.close()
for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if "P-" in line:
        print line
```

Comment: Try using `find` and slicing.

Comment: try `print line[line.find("P-")+2 : line.find("P-")+12]`

Answer (score 0):

Kevin was right.  This is what I did.

```
f = open("Active Notship.txt", "r")
searchlines = f.readlines()
f.close()
for i, line in enumerate(searchlines):
    if "P-" in line:
        print line[3:13]
```

Comment: That will not work if `"P-"` is not at the starting of the line. See my comment.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively to `find` and slicing, you could also use a `regular expression`:

```
text = """some text
with many lines
some have a P- and some stuff behind it
like this: P- foo
and others don't
"""

import re
print(re.findall("(?<=P-).{1,10}", text))
```

Output: `[' and some ', ' foo']`